# Returning ArrayList from Function/Script

Tags: powershell

Given the following script:

```
function f {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param()
    Write-Verbose 'f: Start'
    $t = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
    Write-Verbose $t.GetType().Name
    return $t
}

$things = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
$things.GetType().Name
$things = f -verbose
$things.GetType().Name
```

Why wouldn't the `$things` be-of-type `ArrayList` at the final line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Outputting collections (not just arrays) causes PowerShell to *enumerate* them by default** - i.e., the collection's elements are sent *one by one* to the success output stream.

- If you collect these elements by capturing the output in a variable, you always get a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`), except if there's only *one* element, which is captured as-is.

To prevent that - i.e., **to output a collection *as a whole*** - use:

```bash
Write-Output -NoEnumerate $t
```

A **shorter and more efficient, but less obvious alternative** is to wrap the collection in an auxiliary single-element array with the unary form of `,`, the array-construction operator, which causes PowerShell to enumerate the outer array and output the collection within as-is:

```bash
, $t    # implicit output, no Write-Output needed
```

Note:

- **While outputting collections as a whole is *more efficient*, it is *generally best avoided***, as it may confound callers that expect PowerShell's usual, streaming enumeration behavior (one-by-one object output).