a PS script that finds user day off data always returns the number of user it is checking against, even if no day off
I have a script that runs in strictmode 2.0, Its purpose is to check for day's off based on username and date range. It seems i pass one hundle another pops up. There could be days when nobody is off, but the function always returns 15, which happens to be the number of users its checking for. I would like to know why it returns 15 and how to have it return nothing if nobody is off.
function GetTimeoffData($startDate, $endDate, $teamUsers) {
  Log-Message "INFO" $("Fetching timeoff data from Google Calendar")
  $timeoff = @()
  $URL = "https://search.com/v1/timeoffs/?timeMin=$startDate&timeMax=$endDate"
 
  try {
    if($teamUsers -notcontains "jdoe"){
      $userList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
      $userList.AddRange($teamUsers)
      $userList.Add("jdoe")
    }
    foreach ($user in $userList){
      $body = @{
      "users" = @($user)
      } | ConvertTo-Json -compress
 
      $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
 
      if ($response.StatusCode -eq "200") {
        $data = ConvertFrom-Json $response
        write-host "data: " $data
        foreach($element in $data){
          $offDates = try{$element.items.timeoffs.start.date} catch { }
          write-host "offdates: " $offDates
          if($offDates -ne $null){
              $timeoff += @{
              username = $element.items.username
              date = $element.items.timeoffs.start.date | Sort-Object
            }
          }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
  catch {
      Log-Message "ERROR" $("Unable to fetch timeoff data")
      Log-Message "ERROR" $_.exception.message
  }
  write-host $timeoff
  return $timeoff
}

console out of above function, note the '15'
1727127654 INFO Fetching timeoff data from Google Calendar
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:

1727127694 INFO Processing team Information Security
15
1727127694 ERROR Failed to filter timeoff data
1727127694 ERROR The property 'Length' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

1727127694 STOP Process Stops

$teamUsers is just usernames
PS C:\Users> $teamUsers.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


Tested just function in console:
PS C:\Users> $offtime = GetTimeoffData $startDate $endDate $teamUsers
1727128636.01472 INFO Fetching timeoff data from Google Calendar
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:
data:  @{items=System.Object[]}
offdates:

PS C:\Users> $offtime
15
PS C:\Users> $offtime.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType


due to this '15', it cause a cascading problem because the return data of above function get's passed to another function belong which throws error ERROR The property 'Length' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists as seen above.
function FilterTimeoffData($timeoff, $teamUsers) {
  $info = [String]::Empty
  try {
    #$filteredTimeoff = @($timeoff).Where({ $_.teams -contains $team.name })
    write-host $timeoff
    if ($Timeoff -ne $null) {
      for($i=1; $i -lt $timeoff.Length; $i++) {
        $info += $($timeoff[$i].username + " out: " + $timeoff[$i].date + "`n")
      }
    }
  }
  catch{
    Log-Message "ERROR" $("Failed to filter timeoff data")
    Log-Message "ERROR" $_.exception.message
  }
  return $info
}

As a scenario test, if i use a wider date range the scripts does not error because it has more data. I've tried to null out the $timeoff it no users are off and it always has the 15. any advice to solve around this problem would be helpful.

Your GetTimeoffData as posted isn’t valid Powershell - I get this if I try to run it here - Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.. Can you check what you’ve posted is what you’re actually running, and that the code in your post exhibits the same issue you’ve got in your original script…

Hi @mclayton , I originally removed a part, I have reposted the gettimeoffdata function.  I also re-ran it in console and looks good.

This is the bit that is probably outputting 15 from your function: $userlist.Add(“jdoe”). The ArrayList.Add method returns an integer (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=net-8.0), and since you’re not capturing it the value is being implicitly output from your function. Capture the return value with $null = $userlist.Add(“jdoe”) to prevent it being returned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070774/how-can-i-return-an-arraylist-in-a-powershell-function-without-the-indices-becom for a duplicate question…

Hi @mclayton, That was the cause. Tested solution you provided and worked. Not sure how to mark this as resolved by you.  Many Thanks!

@neoluu you can't unless they post it as an answer, in which case you can accept it

It's a duplicate, so no answer required - see the linked question in the "close" panel at the top of the page for the answer and a full description :-).
